# Keeping track of data version in Mongo DB

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I need to return a JSON of data from MongoDB. I'm using Ruby as my backend. For the clients, I need to supply a data_version string, so they know whether the data has changed or not, to decide whether to sync or load from their storage.

Is there a way to increment this automatically? Or any good practices?

Answer (score 1):

When you use MongoDB you can add timestamps to your documents. This adds two fields: `created_at` and `updated_at`. You can use the value of the `updated_at` field to do what you want.

Comment: hmm, that's a good thought. I could even extract that from BSON::ObjectId. But what if I have a large collection, and I just want to have a quick way of looking up when it as a whole was changed or rather what version it is?

Comment: @DmitryKharlamov Then your "version" wouldn't be linked to a document (or it would be a huge waste of space). You can look up last update by querying your collection with ordering by `updated_at` (in descending order) and then get the last update like that...

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I want - to not link it to a single document, but rather indicate when the whole dataset was changed and your comments were very helpful! Thanks!